# C# Program. Having Issue with Converting Array to String

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Okay, so I am trying my hardest to create a "simple" program that takes a file of answers. I have tried adding a key inside the code and then using StreamReader to compare that key to an uploaded file to the bin. The first error that I receive is #CS0622. It seems that it is not recognizing the values.

What I am trying to do, is to have the uploaded file to be compared to the answer key, and if the "person" answers enough of the questions correctly, to have it display "Pass", if not "Fail". And also while displaying number of correct answers, number of incorrect, and which ones the individual got wrong.

So, lets apply that to the code that I have already written, and I would greatly appreciate any help on how to get this code corrected and fixed. If I need to answer any questions about anything that I might be missing out on, feel free to ask:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string testkey = { 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A' };

        const int Size = 20;
        string[] answers = new string[Size];

        Int index = 0;

        StreamReader inputFile;
        inputFile = File.OpenText("Response.txt");

        while (index < numbers.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            numbers[index] = inputFile.ReadLine();
            index++;
        }
        inputFile.Close();                 
    }

    void gradeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clicking will grade Response.txt file in bin against testkey

    }

    class Int
    {
        public static implicit operator Int(int v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly remove irrelevant codes from the post and say what is the actual issue that you are facing

Comment: That is the issue, I am stuck at the ' string testkey = { 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A' }; 

I am not sure how to fix this, and then after that how to make pass/fail comment to show in a label
'

Comment: Ahh yes, error 0622 somewhere in this code.

Comment: @Plutonix I am getting the error message at the string test key =...

This is where I am getting stuck

Comment: well that string = is not valid syntax. Strings are just strings not arrays of things

Comment: you declared testkey  as string then proceed to try and assign an array to it...just like the error says

Comment: You should declare it as `var testKeys = new[] { 'B', 'D'.... }`

Comment: Well, I am extraordinarily new at programming.

Comment: What you are expecting in `testkey` string. string array or a character arry?, Where you are going to use the value of this `testkey `

Comment: I am trying to use that as the answer key when I use StreamReader to read a file @un-lucky

Comment: @un-lucky I am hoping to use the test key on gradeButton_Click to run everything together

Comment: I am trying to have the key inline so that when I write the for for gradeButton_Click, I will use in some way StreamReader to compare the txt file to the key string. I think I am making this more difficult than I should, but I am a newbie just trying to learn this, and trying to make it work. 

[link](http://imgur.com/9iAv1I4)

That link will display the idea of the program. I hope this helps some

Answer (score 1):

`String` is already an array of `char`, but that does not mean you can freely insert a `char` to a `string` variable (I didn't say you can't).
You can declare the string by `String testkey = "ABC...";` and access it per element by using the index, i.e : `testkey[0]` is "A".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that 'string testkey = { 'B', 'D', ...' syntax is wrong.
A string is a single immutable object containing (internally) an array of chars.
It seems that are attempting to create an array of chars but doing so by attempting to create a string.

string testkey = "abcde";   is valid
char[] testkey = {'a', 'b', 'c'}   is valid.

What you're doing is mixing the two up (not valid!).

Good luck!

Comment: This helps tremendously, I changed it to char[] and that worked.

I am not sure how write the code for the gradeButton_Click to display the Pass/Fail feature that I am wanting, could you possibly help me with this?

Comment: Hi, 
The hard bit was getting the declaration right.  I think you'll work the rest out and enjoy solving it to boot.  
But definitely get rid of your 'Int' class - .Net has all the classes you need at this level.